Ubuntu 24.04 LTS speaker issues
I'm having audio issues after installing Ubuntu 24.04 on my ThinkPad Carbon X1 Gen 9 laptop. The headphone output works fine, but the speakers themselves don't produce any sound. In the settings, I see the audio meter moving up and down whenever audio is played, but there's no sound from the speakers.
I've tried a few recommendations, like blacklisting snd_soc_avs in the alsa-base config file, but still no luck.
What I find odd is that in Alsamixer, both the "Speaker" and "Bass Speaker" are set to zero, and I'm unable to change the levels. Maybe that has something to do with it?

What worked for me was to install the alsa-firmware-loaders package.

Are you using a X1 Gen 9 as well? My speakers seem to be working now, but I have no mic input... Does your internal mic work after installing the package?

I have a X1 Gen 7 and my internal mic works after installing the package.
